# Playwright get text of a p element with strong tag inside

Tags: playwright

I have the following DOM:

```
<p>
<strong>Success!<strong>
"1 item(s) added to cart!"
</p>
```

How can I get the text "Success!1 item(s) added to cart!"?
I want to verify that this element is visible on the page and contains this text.

I tried to use this as a locator:

```
this.successMessage = page.locator('text=Success!1 item(s) added to cart!');
```

but when I do:

```
  public async getSuccessMessageText(): Promise<string | null> {
  return await this.successMessage.textContent();
  }
```

And:

```
const successMessageText = categoryPage.getSuccessMessageText();
expect(successMessageText).toBe(messagesData.successAddToCartMessage);
```

The test breaks with:

```
Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: "Success!1 item(s) added to cart!"
Received: {}
```

Is it possible that the `<strong>` tag is making troubles for the `textContent()` function?  How to retrieve this text otherwise?
Can you please help?

Comment: Did you try `await categoryPage.getSuccessMessageText();` and `await page.locator('text=Success!1 item(s) added to cart!');`? All promises need to be awaited if you want to use the values. `return await this.successMessage.textContent();` can just be `return this.successMessage.textContent();`.

Comment: @ggorlen Yes! That was it. Thanks a ton! I often fall to this pit of Promise hells :)

Comment: No problem--just `await` everything from Playwright. It's running the browser as a subprocess, so there's time out of process waiting for a repsonse that doesn't make sense to freeze Node during, so these APIs are almost always async.